# How do I select a value I've inserted above, in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a stored procedure to generate a survey for a property.
It first receives a `property id` input.
Then, it inserts a new survey in my `survey` table, with an automatically incremented `survey id`, and the corresponding `property id` input.

Lastly, the procedure performs a series of selects and joins, and retrieves all the `questions` that are associated with the `property type` of the `property` in question.
This isn't the relevant part, as it's working perfectly and smoothly.

So before, my stored procedure inserted the survey, and showed a table with one column `question_description` with all the questions for that property's survey in its rows. Here was that code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateSurvey (IN input INT)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO survey (property_id, cas_eval_id, checksum_xxx)
    VALUES
    (input, 'CAS-XXX-YYYY', 123);

    SELECT subquery.question_description
    FROM (
    SELECT question.question_description,
    property_type_question.property_type_id
    FROM property_type_question
    JOIN question
    ON property_type_question.question_id = question.id
    ORDER BY question.id
    ) AS subquery
    JOIN property
    ON subquery.property_type_id = property.property_type_id
    WHERE property.id = input;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that along with the shown questions, I now want to show the ID of the survey said questions belong to.
So to do that, I'm trying this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateSurvey (IN input INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO survey (property_id, cas_eval_id, checksum_xxx)
    VALUES
    (input, 'CAS-XXX-YYYY', 123);

    SELECT survey.id AS 'Survey ID',
    subquery.question_description
    FROM (
    SELECT question.question_description,
    property_type_question.property_type_id
    FROM property_type_question
    JOIN question
    ON property_type_question.question_id = question.id
    ORDER BY question.id
    ) AS subquery
    JOIN property
    ON subquery.property_type_id = property.property_type_id
    WHERE property.id = input;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This is giving me the following error:
[image]

So MySQL isn't recognizing `survey.id`.
But `survey.id` does exist. It's just being inserted in the very same query above, and it just doesn't appear in the code because it's an auto-incremented primary key for my `survey` table.

So how do I keep my procedure's abilities of:

- Inserting a survey
- Showing the survey's questions

And add the ability for it to also display the survey's id along with the questions?

I'm using Uwamp and MySQL Workbench 6.2.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `survey.id` is an `AUTO INCREMENT` column, you can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to fetch its value. With no argument,

> `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

So you can just change

```
SELECT survey.id AS 'Survey ID',
```

to

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'Survey ID',
```

To get the last value of `survey.id`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's complaining is that there is no `survey` it can refer to in your second query, you only have `subquery` and `property`. There's a neat trick you can do to actually get the ID of the last inserted row: [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). So just rewrite your procedure as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateSurvey (IN input INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO survey (property_id, cas_eval_id, checksum_xxx)
    VALUES
    (input, 'CAS-XXX-YYYY', 123);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS 'Survey ID',
    subquery.question_description
    FROM (
    SELECT question.question_description,
    property_type_question.property_type_id
    FROM property_type_question
    JOIN question
    ON property_type_question.question_id = question.id
    ORDER BY question.id
    ) AS subquery
    JOIN property
    ON subquery.property_type_id = property.property_type_id
    WHERE property.id = input;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And you should be good to go.